# DataGrid trailing space after last column

Tags: wpf, datagrid

In a wpf datagrid if the datagrid is wider than the sum of the column widths, you get trailing space.  By default, clicking in this area does not select the row nor does the selection row highlighting cover this area.

How can you register clicks from this area into selecting the appropriate row and also allow the selection row highlighting to extend into this area.

This question:
[WPF DataGrid full row selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518807/wpf-datagrid-full-row-selection)
is similar but I cannot add a dummy column nor set my column widths to *.

Comment: Are you not allowed (e.g. per specification) to set column width to * or don't you know how to do it?

Comment: Yeah, it's unfortunate, I went with the * option (in the link above) but that lead to other problems.  It's a little complicated in the datagrid area can't be that big (and there are a fair number of columns) so it needs the horizontal scrollbar.  Users also need to be able to hide and reorder columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<DataGrid Name="dg">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="DataGridRow_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

with this code behind

```
private void DataGridRow_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    dg.SelectedIndex = (sender as DataGridRow).GetIndex();
}
```

should work.